# 301 redirect the old domain with a certain link to a new domain with the same link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect, folder-redirection

I have a problem, I want to redirect htaccess
The content of domainold.com is still used, only this URL has changed

from the Old website, namely http://domainold.com/product/register

to my new site, namely http://domainnew.com/product/register how to do it, I have tried the method

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\-old\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\-old\.com$
RewriteRule ^product\/register\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/domain\-new\.com\/product\/register\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

but can't, can you help me to solve this problem?? please help !!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem,

That's usually why people post here. No need to assert it.

> I want to redirect htaccess

No - you want to implement a redirect and htaccess is one of the places you can do that.

> I have tried the method....but can't,

Can't what? Were you able to add this to the config? What happenned?

Assuming that you put the config in a file named .htaccess and your webserver is configured to check the .htaccess files and the webserver is apache...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\-old\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\-old\.com$
```

All the rewriteCond rules must be satisifed before the rewrite rule is applied - but your rules are mutually exclusive. The hostname cannot have 2 different values.

Try replacing these 2 lines with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\-old\.com$
```

Comment: no. I've found that answer before, not from you but from others. thanks for that

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer from next door, thank you for your help
this is link [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77414644/301-redirect-the-old-domain-with-a-certain-link-to-a-new-domain-with-the-same-li?noredirect=1#comment136481052_77414644)

Thank's brother @[CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)